# jQuery select box onchange event

Tags: php, jquery, html, onchange

I have a code like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#book_id').change(function(){
        $('#book_code').show();
        var get_value = $(this).val();
        $( "#book_code" ).html( get_value );
    });
});



<td>
    <select id="book_id" name="book_name" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Book</option>
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($book_query)){?>
        <option value="<?php  echo $row['book_code'];?>">
        <?php  echo $row['book_name']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php  }?>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="book_code">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Book Code" />
    </div>
</td>
```

What i want to do is
On each select event, i need to show the book code inside a input text box (not editable)

The above code works but doesn't show the value inside the input box

How can I do that?

In other words, on each select event display the book code inside a text box

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this ([Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/p8L2s/1/)) :

```
$(function() {
   $('#book_id').on('change', function(){
       $('#book_code').find('input').val($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the class of input as well

```
 $(function() {
                $('#book_id').change(function(){
                var get_value = $(this).val();
                $( "#book_code .form-control"  ).val( get_value );
                });
            });
```

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Yeah no need for that...thnx 4 d suggestion

Comment: //Why $('#book_code').show(); ? // my poor bad memory doing silly things. :) but still, learnt a lot through SOF :)